# res.locals in app.use not working, but sending options on res.render does

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Pug file:

```
...
- var paths = flatSitemap(sitemap);
```

app.js file:

```
var fsm = require('./routes/fsm.js');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4109);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src/pug'));
console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'src/pug'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.flatSitemap = fsm.flatSitemap;
  next();
});
app.locals.flatSitemap = fsm.flatSitemap;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('./index', {flatSitemap: fsm.flatSitemap});   // works!!!
  res.render('./index');                                   // Not working
});
```

So when I use the res.render using the options it works, but if I don't include the options and rely on pug reading res.locals it doesn't, and comes back with "flatSitemap is not a function".

Comment: Is there a typo? `flatSitemap` is not in `res.locals`. What's in `res.locals` is `fileSitemap`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Changed it. But that was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `res` object is not automatically passed to the view. Hence the message that `flatSitemap` does not exist or is not a function. You won't get around appending it as a parameter. You can make a condition with a binary logic OR operator.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('./index', { flatSitemap: res.locals.flatSitemap || fsm.flatSitemap });
});
```